# Table in TableViewController is populated before data is received

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to send POST and GET requests to a service. Since I'm using it throughout the app, I made a wrapper class with these two functions:

```
    // An HTTP GET call
func get(urlString:String, body:AnyObject?, completion:(data:AnyObject?, error:NSError?, operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation) -> ())
{
    var operation = self.GET(urlString,
        parameters: body,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            completion(data: (responseObject), error: nil, operation: operation)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            completion(data: nil, error: error, operation: operation)
        }
    )
}

// An HTTP POST call
func post(urlString: String, body: AnyObject?, completion:(data:AnyObject?, error:NSError?, operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation) -> ())
{
    var operation = self.POST(urlString,
        parameters: body,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            completion(data: (responseObject), error: nil, operation: operation)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            completion(data: nil, error: error, operation: operation)
        }
    )
}
```

The problem is when I use them in a TableViewController. Since the methods are running async (I believe), the table is created before the data is receieved. This is the TVC:

```
class ShopViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var stores = [PartnerStore]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadStores()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int
{
    return 3;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
// placeholder value
    return 1;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PartnerShopCell") as PartnerStoreTableViewCell

    cell.storeLogoImageView.image = UIImage();
    cell.storeNameLabel.text = self.stores[indexPath.row].name;

    return cell;

}

func loadStores()
{
    var networkManager:APIClient = APIClient.sharedInstance
    networkManager.get("partner_stores/", body: nil, completion:  {
        (data:AnyObject?, error:NSError?, operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation)  in

        self.stores = data as [PartnerStore]
        println("Data \(self.stores)");
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        if (!error) {

        } else {
            println(error)
            println (operation.response.statusCode)
        }

        });
}
}
```

When I run the app, I get an "Array index out of range" error, because at the time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, the get call hasn't yet finished.

I was thinking about using GCD, but I'm not sure if this is going to help. Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: you returned 1 for `numberOfRowsInSection` do you have only one row?

Comment: It's just a placeholder value, because I can't parse the data and check how many rows should be.

Comment: thats why you are getting the out of index error you should return `self.stores[indexPath.row].count` @smeshko

Comment: No, the problem is, that there is nothing in `self.stores`, when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, so the line `cell.storeNameLabel.text = self.stores[indexPath.row].name;` throws the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error `Array index out of range` because you hardcoded the number of rows in you delegate method, it should be the count of your `datasource` so that when the download is finsih and you reload the `tableView` data the count gets updated since you are loading asynchronously:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  return self.stores[indexPath.row].count
}
```